# Odoo POS (v9) Error (Document type: ir.filters, Operation: read) when validate order

Tags: odoo, xml-rpc, odoo-9

[image]

When POS tries to push orders data to the server, it always appears error like this (on the picture). I've already added access right ir.filters to the user group. But it does not help anything. Only the Administrator can do without this error appear.

**[EDIT]**
Here is the setting :
[image: Access Right]

Comment: you've got the answer yourself. only the admin can do it. it is because the user don't have permission over ir.filters

Comment: the problem is, I want to give access to other users, I've added the user to the user group setting but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Please check "ir.filters" model there is no access rights on given model to particular user.

as admin he have a full access rights on same model.

So now please Just go to `settings` → `Users` → `groups` → check your user group who can not access the records.

Just go to form view of group and Access right tab there please try to check access right given on "ir.filters" model may be there is only given read rights to particular group of user just add few more there then you can create record then.

you also need to go to menu `Technical` → `Security` → `Record Rules`. then search for all record rules related to `ir.filters` model. make sure that the user is not restricted by any of them.

Let us know if it will work for you.

Comment: as I told on my question, I've added "ir.filters" object to the access right of the user group... but it doesn't work...

Comment: check that there are no record rules that restrict the user then. I mean that there is no group assigned to the user that limit or restrict him from updating the record.